# Changing a value in multiple files at the same time in Python

Tags: python

I want to change the value of  `beta` in `Test.py` which are in multiple folders at the same time without actually opening these files but I am getting an error. How do I do this?

```
import os
N=[8,10, 23,29, 36, 37, 41,42, 45, 46, 47]
I=[]

for i in N:
    os.read(rf'C:\Users\User\{i}\Test.py')
    beta=1e-1
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    os.read(rf'C:\Users\User\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\All_ND\var_6.0_beta_0.1\{i}\220_beta_1.0_50.0_6.0ND.py')

TypeError: read expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

Comment: "I want to change the value of beta in Test.py" What does this mean? Are you trying to re-write the source code? Why? "without actually opening these files" That is impossible, by definition; opening a file **is exactly the process** of making it possible to read and/or write to the file, from your program, until it is closed. I also can't understand why `os.read` is supposed to be helpful for solving the problem, or else what practical problem you think exists here in the first place. **Why not** open the file in the normal way?

Comment: Also: please do not use irrelevant tags for the question. It does not matter if the project uses Numpy; the Numpy tag is for questions where *knowing something about Numpy is necessary in order to answer the question*.

Comment: I have 11 files here. I just want to change the value of ```beta``` in each file without opening each individually on Spyder.

Comment: Oh, you mean without **using another program** (in this case, Spyder) to open the file. Okay, yes; you would want to write code that opens and then edits the file. However, simply having `beta = 1e-1` in the code won't change the contents of the file. You need to study the **general topic** of reading and writing files.

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax: os.read(fd, n)
>
> Parameter: fd: A file descriptor representing the file to be read. n:
> An integer value denoting the number of bytes to be read from the file
> associated with the given file descriptor fd

Seems like you forgot the second argument `n`.

see - [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-read-method/#:~:text=read()%20method%20in%20Python,bytes%20left%20to%20be%20read](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-read-method/#:%7E:text=read()%20method%20in%20Python,bytes%20left%20to%20be%20read).